# Time::Piece to display Yesterday's Date

Tags: perl

I would like to display yesterday’s date using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) and overloaded stringification and arithmetic operations like below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

say "    Today is " . localtime;
say "Yesterday is " . localtime - ONE_DAY;
```

[Outputs](http://ideone.com/wb760V):

```
    Today is Mon Sep 22 15:09:00 2014
Yesterday is Tue Dec 30 16:00:00 1969
```

However, as can be observed, today’s date works, but yesterday’s is around epoch.

One solution is by creating a variable for before doing the math `$today - ONE_DAY`. Additionally, the following alternative formats reveal more information:

```
my $fmt = '%Y-%m-%d';

say "Yesterday is ", ( localtime - ONE_DAY         )->strftime($fmt);
say "Yesterday is ", ( +localtime - ONE_DAY        )->strftime($fmt);
say "Yesterday is ", ( scalar(localtime) - ONE_DAY )->strftime($fmt);
say "Yesterday is ", ( - ONE_DAY + localtime       )->strftime($fmt);
```

[Outputs](http://ideone.com/wPeS6J):

```
Yesterday is 1969-12-30
Yesterday is 1969-12-30
Yesterday is 2014-09-21
Yesterday is 2014-09-21
```

The 3rd and 4th methods above work as desired.

So what’s the deal?

Answer (score 6):

This can be diagnosed using [`B::Deparse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) to view how perl interprets the code:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -MO=Deparse -e '
          print "Yest is " . localtime - ONE_DAY
          '
print 'Yest is ' . localtime(-86400);
-e syntax OK
```

So the problem is that [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) is treating the `- ONE_DAY` as its optional parameter and the [Minus operator `-`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators) is switching to its unary context.

This is fixed simply using additional parenthesis:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

say "Today is " . localtime;
say " Yest is " . (localtime() - ONE_DAY);
```

[Outputs](http://ideone.com/EOYR4m):

```
Today is Mon Sep 22 16:25:45 2014
 Yest is Sun Sep 21 16:25:45 2014
```